# Apache Flex 4.9.0 and minimum Flash Player version

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder, flash

Apache flex 4.9.1 needs minimum Flash Player 11.1.

I read that Apache flex 4.9.0 is working with Flash Player 10.2 is that right? I can't find it anywhere! Where can I download it from?

Thanks!

Comment: This is false. As it says minimum FlashPlayer Version is 11.1

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu There has been some work done to lower minimum Flash Player requirements; but the releases always target the latest version.  I believe that Pontifex will have to build the SDK from scratch.  There should be instructions in the Flex repository somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to build the SDK from scratch, Apache Flex 4.9/4.10/4.11 will work with Flash Player 10.2 and above out of the box, 11.1 is not the minimum version. All you need to do is change the configuration file (framework/flex-config.xml) to use 10.2 rather than the default 11.1 and download the correct player global swc. The Apache Flex README has more details instructions on how to do this.

https://github.com/apache/flex-sdk/blob/develop/README

Alternatively the installer (version 2.7 or above) will allow you the select the Flash Player version.

http://flex.apache.org/installer.html

That being said some features may work poorly (eg mobile components) and it hasn't been fully tested on Flash Player 10.2.